# Send SELECT query via ODBC -- how to make pass-through

Tags: ibm-midrange, ms-access-2003, pass-through

I have the following SQL. I've copnnected to a database FPR500 via ODBC, but this is taking forver and I would like a away to convert this to a pass through query. Im getting stuck with the syntax though and am hoping someone can help?

```
SELECT FPR500_SFFD.POL_ID, FPR500_SFFD.CVG_NUM, FPR500_SFFD.FIA_EFF_DT
FROM   FPR500_SFFD 
INNER JOIN FPR500_SFFC 
 ON  (FPR500_SFFD.FIA_EFF_DT = FPR500_SFFC.LATST_CIA_DT) 
 AND (FPR500_SFFD.CVG_NUM    = FPR500_SFFC.CVG_NUM) AND
     (FPR500_SFFD.POL_ID     = FPR500_SFFC.POL_ID)
GROUP BY FPR500_SFFD.POL_ID, 
         FPR500_SFFD.CVG_NUM, 
         FPR500_SFFD.CFN_INTG_AUNIT_QTY,
         FPR500_SFFD.CFN_DCML_AUNIT_QTY, 
         FPR500_SFFD.FIA_EFF_DT
HAVING (((FPR500_SFFD.POL_ID)=[Pol ID]));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What have you tried that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The database is called DB2 for i.  Here is the [SQL Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzmst02.htm) for the oldest supported version of the OS (V5R4).

Without seeing the error message, it looks like the HAVING clause might be the problem.  You don't need all the parentheses, and host variables are designated with a leading colon.

```
HAVING FPR500_SFFD.POL_ID = :Pol_ID
```

Do you really want to group by the quantities?  They aren't being referenced in the SELECT clause...

Comment: Here's another reference, this one a PDF you can download and keep locally: http://mysite.verizon.net/Graeme_Birchall/id1.html

Comment: PDFs of the manuals are available directly from the [IBM i Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/)